# additional key-value pairs in class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am an absolute beginner with python. I wonder if I can use additional key-value pairs in Class()?

```
class Users():   
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **others):    
        for key, value in others.items():   
            self.key = value     
        self.first = first_name    
        self.last = last_name     
    def describe_user(self):      
        print("The user's first name is " + self.first)     
        print("The user's last name is " + self.last)       
        for key, value in others.items():     
            print("The user's " + key + " is " + value)

user1 = Users('Joseph', 'Wilson', age = '18', location = 'California')  
print(user1.location)   
user1.describe_user()
```

Error:

> ```
> AttributeError: 'Users' object has no attribute 'location'   
> NameError: name 'others' is not defined
> ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of

```
self.key = value
```

you want to use

```
setattr(self, key, value)
```

to set the attribute.

All together, you could do something like this:

```
class Users():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **others):
        for key, value in others.items():
            setattr(self, key, value)
        self.first = first_name
        self.last = last_name
    def describe_user(self):      
        for attribute in dir(self):
            if attribute.startswith("__"):
                continue
            value = getattr(self, attribute)
            if not isinstance(value, str):
                continue
            print("The user's " + attribute + " is " + value)

user1 = Users('Joseph', 'Wilson', age='18', location='California')  
print(user1.location)   
user1.describe_user()
```

You could easily use a `dict` to store the information, too.

```
class Users():
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, **others):
        self.data = dict()
        for key, value in others.items():
            self.data[key] = value
        self.data["first name"] = first_name
        self.data["last name"] = last_name
    def describe_user(self):      
        for key, value in self.data.items():
            print("The user's {} is {}".format(key, value))

user1 = Users('Joseph', 'Wilson', age=18, location='California')
print(user1.data["location"])
user1.describe_user()
```

Comment: Also `others` isn't defined in `describe_user`; it isn't carried over from `__init__`.